# RenderMonkey not recognising my variables

Tags: hlsl, shader, rendermonkey

My HLSL shader takes a parameter:

`, uniform float4x4 wm`

Putting this into RM I get an error : *"Missing shader constant parameter named '$wm'"*
I created a 4x4 matrix variable `wm` but it doesn't change anything (and you aren't allowed to add `$wm`).
How am I supposed to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should show all of your shader code and screenshot of RenderMonnkey.
Or giving RenderMonkey project file(.rfx) is the best way to get the answer.